# Segmentation Fault when allocating memory to a pointer to pointer variable [C]

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to represent an array of strings by using a pointer to pointer. So I've defined `char** arr` as below:

```
uint8_t lines = getLines();
char** arr = malloc (sizeof (char*) * lines);
// char** arr = malloc (sizeof (char*) * ROWS_COUNT);
```

In the debug process, the line above will be executed successfully and allocates memory to `arr`. The problem (and so, the error) issues when trying to allocating enough memory to hold a string within `*(arr + 0)` as below:

```
// #define PATH_MAX 4096
*arr = malloc (sizeof (char) * (PATH_MAX + 1));
```

Runtime Error:

```
Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

Note: I've used casting operators (the first assignment by `char**` and the second one by `char*`). It doesn't work too.

**Note:** I've used `ROW_COUNTS` here for the sake of simplicity. In the original code, there is a `lines` variable which I use instead of `ROWS_COUNT`. `lines` contains an `uint8_t` value. (in my case, `3`)

Comment: This seems OK, can you post more code ?

Comment: Those two lines won't cause a segfault (unless there's something strange going on with `ROWS_COUNT` or `PATH_MAX`). Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It's all; there are no more related lines to the subject. I've used ROW_COUNT here for simplicity. Actually, I'm using a variable named `lines` instead; which is containing the value of `3`. `PATH_MAX` (which I think is system dependent) is a constant which defines the MAX path length on Linux systems.

Comment: If `malloc` triggers a seg-fault, you've possibly corrupted your heap with some other code in the "hundreds of lines" prior to this allocation (quoting *you*  from your comment in one of the answers below). With only what you've shown here, the best you can hope for are wags (wild-ass-guesses). This site isn't about guesses; it's about *answers*. Provide a [mcve]  or this question will likely be short-lived.

Comment: And btw, `char (*arr)[PATH_MAX+1] = calloc(ROW_COUNT, sizeof *arr);` would seem much simple if you really are just looking to get `ROW_COUNT` number of fixed `char` buffer space. Unless you need independent string pointers for later replacement and freeing, I'd opt for that alternative; single-alloc; single-free.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn about [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)s

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically allocate memory in *single* `malloc()` , Try this code :-

```
char (*arr)[ROWS_COUNT][PATH_MAX + 1] = malloc (sizeof(*arr));
```

and you could access **strings** using :-

```
(*arr)[ index ]
```

and **characters** using :-

```
(*arr)[ row ] [ column ]
```

Example :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PATH_MAX 4096
#define  ROWS_COUNT 500
int main()
{
    char (*arr)[ROWS_COUNT][PATH_MAX + 1] = malloc (sizeof(*arr));
    strcpy((*arr)[400],"Hello World");
    printf("\n String    : %s",(*arr)[400]);
    printf("\n Character : %c",(*arr)[400][2]);
}
```

Output :-

```
 String    : Hello World
 Character : l
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to notice I'm using `ROWS_COUNT` for simplicity here. In the original code, I use a variable named `lines`. (note added to the main post) BTW, it seems a good solution if someone using a constant name as the row counter.

Comment: Note this will require sweeping changes to the remainder of the code that uses `arr` everywhere following this (`arr` will have to be `(*arr)`. The OP, at *most*, needs an array of arrays. Ex: `char (*arr)[PATH_MAX+1] = calloc(ROW_COUNT, sizeof *arr);`

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry I missed  `*` operator .  I have changed to  `sizeof(*arr)`.

Comment: @anoopknr It's still not necessary to have both dimensions  subscripted to get a single allocation.

Answer (score -1):

```
// #define PATH_MAX 4096
*arr = malloc (sizeof (char) * (PATH_MAX + 1));
```

I think this line needs to be within a loop of `ROWS_COUNT` times. So that memory can be allocated for all the rows to be stored.

Tested on MAC with Xcode (Version 9.3 (9E145)), working fine:

```
char** arr = (char**) malloc (sizeof (char*) * 1000);
int i = -1;
while(++i < 1000)
{
    *(arr + i) = (char*) malloc (sizeof (char) * (PATH_MAX + 1));
}
```

Comment: BTW, On the first loop (let's say i = 0), the same statement must be executed. (which leads to an error)

Comment: @noteworthy - I am on a MAC with xcode, Just tested the code that I have added in the answer to preserve formatting. This code works fine. Also I noticed that PATH_MAX is defined as 1024 in syslimits.h.

Comment: If i = 0; Then: *(arr + i) = *(arr + 0) = *arr. So it issues runtime error in the first loop.

Comment: But not in my case even when its *arr or  *(arr + 0). What is the valude of ROWS_COUNT. may you try putting 1000/100 instead of ROWS_COUNT ?

Comment: @ Rizwan - Yeah, I'm confused. It may be related to hundred of lines before this allocation. Also, `PATH_MAX` is system dependent.

Comment: Most probably you are right that its "hundred of lines before this allocation". Please let us know the reason when you find it.

Comment: `ROWS_COUNT` = `3`.

Comment: Ok, I will share the solution. Thanks.

Comment: `i` goes from `1` to `1001` in the loop body of your example, which is an off by 2 error and does not initialize the first element.

Comment: You should use a for loop instead of that icky while loop. `for(size_t i=0; i<1000; i++) { arr[i]  = malloc(...); }` That way you also remove the off-by-one bugs you have written in the current code: `*(arr + 1000) = ` writes out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Actually that was just a quick testing code. Corrected it however. For is good but while was used bcz it needs less keystrokes.

Comment: @Rizwan It is still out of bounds. Only difference you are not off by 2 only by 1.

Comment: "Less keystrokes" is a horrible rationale for writing an algorithm in a certain way. Programming is all about hitting a whole lot of keys on the keyboard. If that's not your thing, then programming isn't for you.